# How to iterate MapReduce in Hadoop? (lang: python)

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I wrote a MapReduce program (mapper.py and reducer.py) to deal with PageRank problem in Hadoop.

I want to iterate the MapReduce about 10 iterations. How can I take the output of the first round MapReduce to the input of the second round MapReduce?

```
       1                    2                           10
[mapper->reducer] -> [mapper->reducer] -> ... -> [mapper->reducer] -> final result
```

Comment: Apache Spark GraphX has PageRank built-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just chain the output of job1 as the input to job2.

inputdir1 -> outputdir1 -> outputdir2 ... -> outputdir9 -> outputdir10